# Component Rendering Above other component, but not below

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a screen in which I have a MenuItem Component and a ViewCard Component. This View Card is supposed to render on top of it. Please see the ViewCard Component Code.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default function ViewCard() {
  return (
    <View
      stlye={{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        position: 'absolute',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        bottom: 130,
        zIndex: 999,
      }}>
      <View
        stlye={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          width: '100%',
        }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            marginTop: 20,
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            alignItems: 'center',
            padding: 13,
            borderRadius: 30,
            width: 300,
            position: 'relative',
          }}>
          <Text style={{ color: 'pink', fontSize: 20 }}>VIEWCART</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

This component is being rendered onto a screen with other components

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Divider } from 'react-native-elements/dist/divider/Divider';
import About from '../components/restaurantDetail/About';
import MenuItem from '../components/restaurantDetail/MenuItem';
import ViewCard from '../components/restaurantDetail/ViewCard';

export default function RestaurantDetail({ route, navigation }) {
  return (
    <View>
      <About route={route} />

      <Divider width={1.8} style={{ marginVertical: 20 }} />

      <MenuItem />
      <ViewCard navigation={navigation} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

When the Viewcard is above the MenuItem Component, it renders,  in between the Divider and Menu Item, but not "above" like on the Z-axis, when it is below it does not render. In the ViewCard, the highest View makes it a zIndex above it as well as makes it a position of absolute with the bottom being placed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `zIndex: 999` try `elevation: 1` where `1` being the stack elevation number, increase it accordingly

Comment: Nope :/ just tried.